# How to rename "Author" label in the WP-admin UI

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wp-admin

Check the screenshot below; all I want to do is to rename the "Author" for all users who get access to the backend. And it would be better if it's a global change.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `manage_edit-post_columns` filter, so add below code to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'rename_author_column' );
function rename_author_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['author'] = 'Posted by';
    return $columns;
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

To change the title of author metabox in single post edits, add this code to your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'change_author_metabox');
function change_author_metabox() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    $wp_meta_boxes['post']['normal']['core']['authordiv']['title']= 'Posted by';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so so much!!!!! That works! Also, could you please help me with "Author"'s display name when you edit the post inside?(localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=10&action=edit).

Comment: I uploaded an another screenshot.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! Btw, do you have any suggested tutorials for changing wp backend?

Comment: What if we want to do this only for a specific post type?